# Rails has_many with two tables (count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about joins (and has_many belongs) ...

I have 3 tables in the database.

**Advertisers**

- id
- name

**Categories**

Linked with Advertisers (gem awesome_nested_set)

**Comments**

- id
- advertiser_id
- comment
- recommend

I can not see how many comments there are on the advertiser, and how many of these comments are recommended.

**Advertisers Data**

```
1 | abc
```

**Comments Data**

```
id | a_id | text    | rec
---+------+---------+-----
 1 | 1    | blabla  | 1
 2 | 1    | blablab | 1
 3 | 1    | blablac | 1
 4 | 1    | blablad | 0
```

In this case there are four comments and three of them are recommended.

In my view, I need to retrieve the following

Listing Category **abapai**

Advertiser name: **abc**

There are **3 comments recommended**

a total of **4**

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments model you can use `scope` method to filter for recommended comments. Like this:

```
scope :recommended_comments, where("recommended = '1'")
```

Then in the Advertiser view you could use it like this (I gussed some attribute names):

```
Listing Category <%= @advertiser.category.name %>    
Advertiser name: <%= @advertiser.name %>    
There are <%= @advertiser.comments.recommended_comments.count %> comments recommended    
a total of <%= @advertiser.comments.count %>
```